# Query HBase table from Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hbase, integration

Here are the environment details:
Hadoop: 2.4.0
Hive: 0.11.0
HBase: 0.94.18

I created a HBase table and imported 10,000 rows:

```
hbase(main):008:0> create 'genotype_tbl', 'cf'
```

Load data to the table.

```
hbase(main):008:0> count 'hbase_tbl'
10000 row(s) in 176.9310 seconds
```

I created a Hive table as described in this article (using instructions on this page: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HBaseIntegration#HBaseIntegration-HiveHBaseIntegration)

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE hive_tbl(key int, value string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf:info") 
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "hbase_tbl");
```

However, when I do a count(*) on hive_tbl, it returns 0. There are no errors of any sort. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved. The problem is with the hbase ImportTsv command. columns list was incorrect. Once, that was resolved, I could execute queries from Hive.